# Reading DataCollection<Entity> from Dynamics CRM using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to pull and read the entity from Dynamics CRM using C#. I am using `retrieveMultiple` method and all I am getting is `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue`. When I debug I see 1000 records but every record is showing the same text `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
QueryExpression bookQuery = new QueryExpression("new_res")
        {
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_book"),
            Criteria =
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression()
                    {
                        AttributeName="new_bookid",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.NotNull
                                            
                    }
                }
            }
        };

DataCollection<Entity> bookList = service.RetrieveMultiple(bookeQuery).Entities;

foreach (var c in bookList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Attributes["new_bookid"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use an `EntityCollection`:

```
EntityCollection bookList = (EntityCollection)service.RetrieveMultiple(bookQuery);

if (bookList.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    var record = bookList.Entities[0];
    var recordNumberString = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to write the cast (EntityCollection) as RetrieveMultiple already returns an EntityCollection